# Elasticsearch Snowball Analyzer wants exact word

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I Have been using Elastic Search for a project, but I find the result of Snowball Analyzer a bit strange.

Below is my example of Mapping used.

```
$myTypeMapping = array(
    '_source' => array(
        'enabled' => true
    ),
    'properties' => array(
        'id'    => array(
            'type'  => 'integer',
            'index' => 'not_analyzed'
        ),
        'name' => array(
            'type' => 'string',
            'analyzer' => 'snowball',
            'boost' => 2.0
        ),
        'food_types' => array(
            'type' => 'string',
            'analyzer' => 'keyword'
        ),
        'location' => array(
            'type' => 'geo_point',
            "geohash_precision"=> 4
        ),
        'city' => array(
            'type' => 'string',
            'analyzer' => 'keyword'
        )
    )
);
$indexParams['body']['mappings']['online_pizza'] = $myTypeMapping;

// Create the index

$elastic_client->indices()->create($indexParams);
```

On quering the `http://localhost:9200/online_pizza/online_pizza/_mapping` I get the following results,

```
    {
  "online_pizza": {
    "properties": {
      "city": {
        "type": "string",
        "analyzer": "keyword"
      },
      "food_types": {
        "type": "string",
        "analyzer": "keyword"
      },
      "id": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "location": {
        "type": "geo_point",
        "geohash_precision": 4
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "string",
        "boost": 2,
        "analyzer": "snowball"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My Question is, I have data, which has `Name` field as "Milano". On querying for "Milano" I get the desired result, but if I query for "Milan" or "Mil" I get no result found.

```
 {
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "name",
      "query": "Milan"
     }
   }
 }
```

I've also tried to snowball analyzer during querying, no help.

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "name",
      "query": "Milan",
      "analyzer": "snowball"
    }
  }
}
```

Second Question is Keyword Search is case sensitive, eg, Pizza != pizza, how do i get away with this ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `snowball` stemmer doesn't want exact words. If you try it with `jumping`, it outputs `jump` as expected.

However, depending on the case, you word may be understemmed as it doesn't match any stemmer rule.

If you use the `analyze` API endpoint (more info [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html#indices-analyze)), you will see that analyzing `Milano` with `snowball` analyzer gives you the token `milano` :

```
GET _analyze?analyzer=snowball&text=Milano
```

Output :

```
{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "milano",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 6,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 1
      }
   ]
}
```

Then, using same snowball analyzer on `Mil` like this :

```
GET _analyze?analyzer=snowball&text=Mil
```

gives you this token :

```
{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "mil",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 3,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 1
      }
   ]
}
```

That's why searching for 'milan' or 'mil' won't match 'Milano' documents : it doesn't match the `milano` term stored in index.

For your second question, you can prepare a `custom` analyzer combining `keyword` tokenizer and a `lowercase` tokenfilter in order to have your keyword search case-insensitive (if you use the same analyzer at search time) :

```
POST index_name
{
  "analysis": {
   "analyzer": {
     "case_insensitive_keyword": {
       "type": "custom",
       "tokenizer": "keyword",
       "filter": ["lowercase"]
     }
   }
  }
}
```

Test :

```
GET analyse/_analyze?analyzer=case_insensitive_keyword&text=Choo Choo
```

Output :

```
{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "choo choo",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 9,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 1
      }
   ]
}
```

I hope I'm clear enough in my explainations :)

Comment: Thankyou for the appropriate answer, Very clear, What should be the analyser used, if I want it to search any character but not using the stemmer rule. Regular Expression ?

Comment: Maybe [ngrams](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_ngrams_for_partial_matching.html) would be the right answer

Comment: Really appreciate you taking time to answer the question which such clarity. thank you so much