# Allowing case-insensitive search with snowball_analyzer in Elasticsearch

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

First of all I'm completly new to ES. I created ES search criteria below for searching items which works fine but what I now need is, I want to turn **make** field into case-insensitive so that the search result would be the same for `hello`, `HeLlo`, `HELLO` so on.

I've read post below couldn't quiet apply to my example below because of my very limited knowledge:

- [Case insensitivity does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266830/case-insensitivity-does-not-work)
- [Elasticsearch Map case insensitive to not_analyzed documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036708/elasticsearch-map-case-insensitive-to-not-analyzed-documents)
- [Elasticsearch Snowball Analyzer wants exact word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26630437/elasticsearch-snowball-analyzer-wants-exact-word)

Removing `not_analyzed` from **make** doesn't help.

```
'indexes' => [
    'my_project' => [
        'client' => 'default',
        'index_name' => 'hello',
        'settings' => [
            'index' => [
                'analysis' => [
                    'analyzer' => [
                        'snowball_analyzer' => [
                            'type' => 'snowball',
                            'language' => 'English',
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'types' => [
            'item' => [
                'mappings' => [
                    'uuid' => ['type' => 'string', 'index' => 'not_analyzed'],
                    'name' => ['type' => 'string', 'boost' => 8, 'analyzer' => 'snowball_analyzer'],
                    'make' => ['type' => 'string', 'index' => 'not_analyzed'],
                ]
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

These is the query that I created:

**1**

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "make": "HeLlo"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no search criteria in the post. Searching for case insensitive is both about mapping and/or the search itself.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the "lowercase" filter. Here is an extract for a similar configuration I use:

```
settings:
    index:
        analysis:
            analyzer:
                custom_search_analyzer:
                    type: custom
                    tokenizer: standard
                    filter: [stopwords, asciifolding ,lowercase, snowball, elision, worddelimiter]
```

In your case, I guess you should change like this:

```
...                    
'settings' => [
    'index' => [
        'analysis' => [
            'analyzer' => [
                'snowball_analyzer' => [
                    'type' => 'snowball',
                    'language' => 'English',
                    'filter' => [ 'lowercase' ]
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],                        
...
```

Comment: I just added `'filter' => [ 'lowercase' ]` bit but no luck.

Comment: I just read that lowercase filter should be enabled by default in snowball, see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-snowball-analyzer.html . So unfortunately my answer does not apply. Sorry for misleading you.

Comment: No problem at all. That happens. Thank you for the effort anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I went thru the answer in [the first link I posted](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) with my eyes open this time and it solved my problem too so my case-insensitive working example is:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
               "query_string": {
                  "query": "HeLlo*"
                }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```